# Firebase cloud functions scheduledFunction gives Error: Process exited with code 16

Tags: node.js, firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions, timestamp

I'm trying to run a scheduled cloud function on firebase. I see this error in the logs when it runs:

```
Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:237:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at process.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:169:15)
    at Object.sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:38:9)
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:233:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at process.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)
```

here is my function:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
 .schedule("every 5 minutes")
 .onRun((context) => {
   console.log("This will be run every 5 minutes!");
   const tsToMillis = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis();
   // const compareDate = new Date(tsToMillis - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
   const compareDate = new Date(tsToMillis - 5 * 60 * 1000);
   admin
     .firestore()
     .collection("properties").where("status", "==", "Reserved")
     .where("reservationDate", "<", compareDate)
     .where("paymentIsDone", "==", false)
     .get()
     .then((querySnapshot) => {
       querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         admin.firestore().collection("properties").doc(doc.id).update({
           agent: "",
           reservedBy: "",
           reservedByPhoneNumber: "",
           reservationDate: null,
           status: "Remaining",
         });
         console.log("canceling reservations");
       });
     });
   return null;
 });
```

I want to cancel reservations on properties that have not completed payment within 24 hours (for testing 5 min) after reservation.

This is how I reserve the property:

```
exports.reserveApt = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    return {
      result: "failed",
      msg: "you are not authenticated",
    };
  }
  const doc = admin.firestore().collection("properties").doc(data.aptId);
  // get apt
  return doc.get().then((apt) => {
    apt = apt.data();
    // check apt is not already reserved or sold
    //   console.log(apt);
    if (apt.status !== "Remaining") {
      return {
        result: "failed",
        msg: "Appartment is already reserved or sold",
      };
    }
    // reserve apt with username and phone and changes status to reserved
    return doc
      .update({
        agent: data.agent,
        reservedBy: data.reserveeName,
        reservedByPhoneNumber: data.reserveePhone,
        reservationDate: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        status: "Reserved",
        paymentIsDone: false,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("apt reserved");
        return {result: "success"};
      });
  });
});
```

Is the problem with the timestamps or what? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a compound query using `.where()` between equality operators (`==` or `array-contains`) and inequality operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, and `!=`), which [is invalid in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).

```js
admin
  .firestore()
  .collection("properties")
  .where("status", "==", "Reserved")  // First query, using equality comparator
  .where("reservationDate", "<", compareDate) // ERROR! You're using inequality operator '<' after '=='
```

To perform such operations, you need to [create an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing); which can be done [following the error message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message) (check your [Cloud Functions](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list), click your function, click on **LOGS** tab and search for the error).